# How to get a flat array as a response from GraphQL server

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, graphql

I am having difficulties with some GraphQL queries to a web service. The issue is slightly complicated hopefully I will try and explain it reasonably.

The issue stems from the fact that one of the fields I am interested in getting is not a scalar but an array. I want to return one value in that array based on string matching, which is not possible with GraphQL alone if I understand correctly.

So I figure I do the filtering in python later on and just grab them all. However in this case the issue is that I cannot easily process the columns since it's an embedded json array in pandas.

The following code shows a minimal example where I get a nested json string (an array of name:value pairs) in the field of `xrefs` instead of an array.

```
query = \
    f"""
    {{
      targets(
        filter: {{
          facets: [{{
            facet: "Target Development Level",
            values: ["Tchem"]
          }}]
        }}
      ) {{
        targets(top:10){{
            xrefs (source: "Ensembl"){{name}}
            sym
            tdl
            uniprot

          }}
      }}
    }}
    """
url = 'https://pharos-api.ncats.io/graphql'
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(json_data['data']['targets']['targets']), orient='records')
```

What I want to achieve in order of preference:

1. Be able to pick a single value from `xrefs`, based on string matching on `name` using only GraphQL
2. Get an array of strings for `xrefs` instead of name:value pairs, again from GQL
3. Get pandas/python to parse and flatten the json for `xrefs` so that I get a list of strings instead of something like:

   [{'name': 'ENST00000260967'},
   {'name': 'ENSP00000260967'},
   {'name': 'ENSG00000138395'},
   {'name': 'ENST00000410091'},
   {'name': 'ENSP00000386901'},
   {'name': 'ENST00000434439'},
   {'name': 'ENSP00000412775'},
   {'name': 'ENST00000450471'},
   {'name': 'ENSP00000406472'}]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```py
import json
import requests

query = f"""
{{
    targets(
    filter: {{
        facets: [{{
        facet: "Target Development Level",
        values: ["Tchem"]
        }}]
    }}
    ) {{
    targets(top:10){{
        xrefs (source: "Ensembl"){{name}}
        sym
        tdl
        uniprot
        }}
    }}
}}
"""

url = "https://pharos-api.ncats.io/graphql"
r = requests.post(url, json={"query": query})
data = r.json()["data"]["targets"]["targets"]

# Flatten the xrefs
for row in data:
    row["xrefs"] = [element["name"] for element in row["xrefs"]]

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```py
[
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000312988",
      "ENSP00000318197",
      "ENSG00000152086"
    ],
    "sym": "TUBA3E",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q6PEY2"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000399635",
      "ENSP00000382544",
      "ENSG00000206203"
    ],
    "sym": "TSSK2",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q96PF2"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000612221",
      "ENSP00000483467",
      "ENSG00000231274"
    ],
    "sym": "SBK3",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "P0C264"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000251472",
      "ENSP00000251472",
      "ENSG00000105613"
    ],
    "sym": "MAST1",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q9Y2H9"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000260967",
      "ENSP00000260967",
      "ENSG00000138395",
      "ENST00000410091",
      "ENSP00000386901",
      "ENST00000434439",
      "ENSP00000412775",
      "ENST00000450471",
      "ENSP00000406472"
    ],
    "sym": "CDK15",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q96Q40"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000238789",
      "ENSP00000238789",
      "ENSG00000119778"
    ],
    "sym": "ATAD2B",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q9ULI0"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000358371",
      "ENSP00000351140",
      "ENSG00000176601",
      "ENST00000375844",
      "ENSP00000365004",
      "ENST00000375845",
      "ENSP00000365005",
      "ENST00000392915",
      "ENSP00000376647",
      "ENST00000392917",
      "ENSP00000376649",
      "ENST00000392918",
      "ENSP00000376650"
    ],
    "sym": "MAP3K19",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q56UN5"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000456354",
      "ENSP00000390423",
      "ENSG00000188782",
      "ENST00000518899",
      "ENSP00000429464"
    ],
    "sym": "CATSPER4",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q7RTX7"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000370435",
      "ENSP00000359464",
      "ENSG00000119900"
    ],
    "sym": "OGFRL1",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q5TC84"
  },
  {
    "xrefs": [
      "ENST00000321751",
      "ENSP00000319778",
      "ENSG00000175756",
      "ENST00000338338",
      "ENSP00000340656",
      "ENST00000338370",
      "ENSP00000342676",
      "ENST00000378853",
      "ENSP00000368130"
    ],
    "sym": "AURKAIP1",
    "tdl": "Tchem",
    "uniprot": "Q9NWT8"
  }
]
```